# Why is the use of a type alias in the constructor of an implicit class causing a compilation error?

Tags: scala

The use of a type alias is causing a compilation error when used in the constructor of an implicit class, as demonstrated in the following example:

```
package demo

object ConditionsDemo {
  type Condition[T] = T => Boolean

  val equalsTo = (right:String) => (left:String) => left == right

  object Implicits1 {
    implicit class RichCondition[T](left:T => Boolean) {
      def ||(right:Condition[T]):Condition[T] = (x:T) => left(x) || right(x)
    }
  }

  val isFooOrBar1 = {
    import Implicits1._
    equalsTo("foo") || equalsTo("bar")
  }

  object Implicits2 {
    implicit class RichCondition[T](left:Condition[T]) {
      def ||(right:Condition[T]):Condition[T] = (x:T) => left(x) || right(x)
    }
  }

  val isFooOrBar2 = {
    import Implicits2._
    equalsTo("foo") || equalsTo("bar")
  }
}
```

`isFooOrBar2` fails to compile with the following error:

```
Error:(27, 21) value || is not a member of String => Boolean
    equalsTo("foo") || equalsTo("bar")
                    ^
```

The only difference between `Implicits1.RichCondition` and `Implicits2.RichCondition` is that the former uses the literal `T => Boolean` in the constructor, while the latter uses the type alias `Condition[T]`.

Why is `isFooOrBar2` causing the compilation error?

Comment: `val equalsTo: String => Condition[String] = (right:String) => (left:String) => left == right` works

Comment: Making `RichCondition` non-generic (and in return more restricitve) also works: `implicit class RichCondition(left:Condition[String]){...`, so I guess the compiler is either smart enough to infer the type parameter `T`, or to figure out that `String => Boolean` is `Condition[T]`, but it can't figure out both at the same time?